Jquery Beginner Question - saving text in a variable and outputting it
I am starting up with Jquery and would like to do the following:
Submit and store a text with Jquery, and replace the text in the HTML with this.
How do I exactly do this?
    <section>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name">
            <input type="submit" id="submit">
            <p class="output">Hello <strong>Text that needs to be replaced</strong></p>
        </section>

I tried something like:
$(function () {
   $( "#name")
   .on ("submit", function() {
    let value = $(this ).val();
    $("strong").text( value );
  });
});

But this didn't work. How can I achieve this?

You have several mistakes in your javascript, it should be


$(function () {
   $("#submit")
   .on("click", function() {
    const value = $("#name").val();
    $("strong").text( value );
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
    <p class="output">Hello <strong>Text that needs to be replaced</strong></p>
</section>




Try this code:
<section>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <input type="submit" id="submit">
        <p class="output">Hello <span id='strong'>Text that needs to be replaced</span></p>
</section>


  $( "#submit").on("click", function() {
    let value = $("#name").val();
    $("#strong").text( value );
  });

Test it here
